# Hide a visual if slicer is selected

Tags: powerbi-desktop, show-hide, slicers

In my power bi report I have a slicer with countries so I can filter all the data for a specific country or to show totals globally.

I also have a card showing the total distinc count of countries. What I am trying to achieve is to hide the visual with total count of countries if any country is selected in slicer and only show this visual if slicer is not selected.

I have found a various ways how to do the opposite, i.e. to show visual only if slicer is selected and hide if not but I need the exact opposite.

Anyone able to crack this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QSm0.png)

tried different dax options but always end up not being able to edit the measure as needed